# Select specific rows of 3D PyTorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

I want to select specific rows of 2d tensor by giving a source tensor and index tensor.

Input:

a = torch.FloatTensor([[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[9,9,9],[5,5,5]]])
b = torch.IntTensor([1,0])

Any solution?

Expect result: [[2,2,2]],[9,9,9]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a great solution.

```
out = a[torch.arange(a.size(0)), b]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using gather method and 2d index

```
a = torch.FloatTensor([[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[9,9,9],[5,5,5]]])
b = torch.LongTensor([1,0])

R = a.shape[0]
C = a.shape[2]

idx = b.unsqueeze(dim=1).repeat(1, C).view(R, 1, C)
torch.gather(a, 1, idx)
```